# Mongod service suddenly stopped at night. Understanding why

Tags: server, upstart, mongodb

I've created a node.js server with a mongodb database on Ubuntu.
I installed mongodb with the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), using `upstart`.

This morning, my node server wake me up with crash logs saying the database was down. This already happened 1 month ago.

So I checked the status

```
> service mongod status  
mongod stop/waiting
```

I restarted it with `sudo service mongod start` and the problem was solved.

But now I want to understand: why did it stopped? How to prevent it to happen again in the future?

I checked my server last reboot.

```
> uptime
09:28:52 up 139 days, 21:34,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
```

Ok, not caused by a system reboot.

I checked the mongod logs:

```
tail -500 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

and I could see my restart log dated to this morning, but nothing at all related to this night!

I'm not a sysadmin guru and I don't know what I can check now to better understand my problem. Anyone could help me?

EDIT:
As requested in the comments, here's my upstart `/etc/init/mongod.conf` file:

```
# Ubuntu upstart file at /etc/init/mongod.conf

# Recommended ulimit values for mongod or mongos
# See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings
#
limit fsize unlimited unlimited
limit cpu unlimited unlimited
limit as unlimited unlimited
limit nofile 64000 64000
limit rss unlimited unlimited
limit nproc 64000 64000

kill timeout 300 # wait 300s between SIGTERM and SIGKILL.

pre-start script
  DAEMONUSER=${DAEMONUSER:-mongodb}
  if [ ! -d /var/lib/mongodb ]; then
    mkdir -p /var/lib/mongodb && chown mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
  fi
  if [ ! -d /var/log/mongodb ]; then
    mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb && chown mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
  fi
  touch /var/run/mongodb.pid
  chown $DAEMONUSER /var/run/mongodb.pid
end script

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

script
  ENABLE_MONGOD="yes"
  CONF=/etc/mongod.conf
  DAEMON=/usr/bin/mongod
  DAEMONUSER=${DAEMONUSER:-mongodb}
  DAEMONGROUP=${DAEMONGROUP:-mongodb}

  if [ -f /etc/default/mongod ]; then . /etc/default/mongod; fi

  # Handle NUMA access to CPUs (SERVER-3574)
  # This verifies the existence of numactl as well as testing that the command works
  NUMACTL_ARGS="--interleave=all"
  if which numactl >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && numactl $NUMACTL_ARGS ls / >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
  then
    NUMACTL="$(which numactl) -- $NUMACTL_ARGS"
    DAEMON_OPTS=${DAEMON_OPTS:-"--config $CONF"}
  else
    NUMACTL=""
    DAEMON_OPTS="-- "${DAEMON_OPTS:-"--config $CONF"}
  fi

  if [ "x$ENABLE_MONGOD" = "xyes" ]
  then
    exec start-stop-daemon --start \
        --chuid $DAEMONUSER:$DAEMONGROUP \
        --pidfile /var/run/mongodb.pid \
        --make-pidfile \
        --exec $NUMACTL $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS
  fi
end script
```

Comment: What about `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log.1`,  `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log.2.gz`, etc.?

Comment: @muru, none of these files. In `/var/log/mongodb/` there's only `mongod.log` and `mongodb.log`, the last corresponds to a previously wrong installation (deleted)

Comment: Without the logs it's going to be hard/impossible to track this down - the first thing I would do is make sure you have `logAppend: true` set.  Just to be sure - are there any log files that look relevant in the folder?  If not you can look in syslog, messages etc. for any mongod related messaging, but only a subset of causes will leave any evidence in those files

Comment: I would check `/var/log/upstart/mongodb.log`. The name of the log file might be different.

Comment: thanks for your comments. @schkovich, I already checked in `/var/log/upstart/`, but only some mongod.log.gz* whoose are not modified since monthes.

Comment: @AdamC, I know it's difficult to track down my problem without logs, that's why i'm asking for other ideas to check for. Yes `logAppend` is already set to `true`. I also checked my `node.js` logs, and nothings seems to be related...

Comment: All that you could do right now is to assure that on the next crash you have logs. Posting mongodb.conf would be helpful.

Comment: @schkovich, included it in my question.

Comment: @Martin I had in mind upstart configuration file. One in `/etc/init/mongodb.conf`.

Comment: @schkovich: done. But it's just standard upstart conf file since I did not edited it after the install.

Comment: @Martin That upstart script is wrong in so many ways. :( Most likely this script is the root of your problem(s). Unfortunately I see no easy way fix it.

Comment: Not helping a lot.